# What is the recommended post cap or strapping for corner post under beam and rim joists?

Tags: joists, post, fastener, brackets, beam

I'm trying to find the appropriate strapping to secure a beam to a post, while providing a means to attach a double rim-joist. Consider the drawings below:

[image]

In both of these drawings if I use a post cap to attach the beam to the post, the metal of the cap interferes with the joist hangers I would use on the rim joists. In the left-hand drawing I can attach half of the rim joist directly to the front of the beam while sitting it on the post, since the beam only needs 3.5" of support. But how would I attach the second half of the rim joist so that it is 'hanging' from the beam?

**What is the correct method for securing the beam to the post, while allowing for the rim joist to be secured to the beam?**

I need to hang the joists off the beam - I cannot set them on top. I am hoping to not have to set-back the beam; I want it centred under the corner as shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are butting a rim joist into the beam, you can frame like the first photo with the beam held back 1-1/2" and the first rim joist extending to the end of the post.

Then, in the corner of the second (inner) rim joist and the beam, attach some Simpson A35's.  1 should do, but if you have enough height you could install 2.  Each A35 can transfer nearly 600lb of gravity load into the beam.  If this truly is a rim joist, then 1,200lb of (2) A35's + the shear on the first rim should be more than enough.

Then use (6+) 3-1/2" quality construction screws (vs cheap deck screws) end screwed through the outer rim into the end of the beam to tie the rim and the beam together.

I would not recommend a Simpson ECC style column cap; these are only needed in extreme (for DIYers) load cases.

Comment: This was my original thought but how to tie post and beam together? The A35 would interfere with whatever I strap the beam with.

Comment: Would a single L bracket like this (http://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/HL_APG.asp) work for the post/beam connection? Then the interior face of the beam is free for the joist

Comment: Yes, that would work, put one on the beam and one on the rim.  You could also use the A35s in those locations as well if you use them in tandem. If this is exterior or supporting a roof you could add an LSTA9 strap from beam to post for uplift as well.  You could also in-liue-of or in-addition-to the aforementioned ideas,  toe screw up through the post  into the beam/rim and recess the heads; maybe a couple per side or 6-8 total;  The longer the better but 4" +/- screws would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Is this for a deck?  If there is sheathing, you could also use it to tie things together.

Comment: It's for a loft in my studio - there's storage underneath and not sheathed, unfortunately.

Comment: @Steven  Well, no uplift then.  Just lateral and gravity.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for the (pricey) Simpson's Strong Tie ECCL

[image]

More info here:  http://www.strongtie.com/products/connectors/eccl-ccc-cct.asp

Comment: I looked at that and the depth of the beam required is too great. Any other options? It would be perfect with the right lumber.

Comment: On reviewing the documentation further, there might be a combination that works for me. I'll contact the nearest simpson vendor to confirm. Still - that price!